# Date format regex to match date separator

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I am using below code to validate the date format in `dd/mm/yyyy` and `dd.mm.yyyy` format.

```
function validateDate(date){
    var matches, d, m, y, cDate, format, dateFormatObj;
    dateFormatObj = { format: /^(\d{2})[./](\d{2})[./](\d{4})$/, monthPos: 2, datePos:1,    yearPos:3}

    format = dateFormatObj.format;
    matches = format.exec(date);

    d = matches[dateFormatObj.datePos];
    m = matches[dateFormatObj.monthPos] - 1;
    y = matches[dateFormatObj.yearPos];
    cDate = new Date(y, m, d);

    return cDate.getDate() == d && cDate.getMonth() == m && cDate.getFullYear() == y;
}

alert(validateDate('22/05/2017'))
```

This works fine for me, to validate basic date.

What i was trying to fix is that if the separator (/ or .) between the month, date and year values are different, then it should invalidate that.

What i tried was to change the regex format as `/^(\d{2})[./](\d{2})\1(\d{4})$/`, basically to use the same captured group as specified, but this doesn't seem to work, the "matches" comes out to be null. I have read couple of posts, but something seems to be missing. What can i do to make this work.

JS Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/90dstrx5/

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/90dstrx5/1/. Use both different formats and check if any on of that matches.

Comment: @Pugazh I dont think it works. if you pass date as "22/05.2017" ,it gives error

Comment: That error is because of invalid date. Is `22/05.2017` a valid date format?

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/90dstrx5/2/

Comment: @Pugazh the idea is to invalidate "22/05.2017" , if users enter this by mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite the regex as follows:

```
/^(\d{2})([./])(\d{2})\2(\d{4})$/
//       ^            ^
//       |            +---- match capturing group #2
//       +----------------- capturing group #2
```

Note that the "numbers" will now be available at 1st, 3rd and 4th position in the result; separator will be at 2nd position. To eliminate any confusion use `Array.splice()` to eliminate it:

```js
function validateDate(date) {
  var matches, d, m, y, cDate, format, dateFormatObj;
  dateFormatObj = {
    format: /^(\d{2})([./])(\d{2})\2(\d{4})$/,
    monthPos: 2,
    datePos: 1,
    yearPos: 3
  };
  format = dateFormatObj.format;
  matches = format.exec(date);
  if (matches === null) {
    return false;
  }
  matches.splice(2, 1);
  d = matches[dateFormatObj.datePos];
  m = matches[dateFormatObj.monthPos] - 1;
  y = matches[dateFormatObj.yearPos];
  cDate = new Date(y, m, d);
  return cDate.getDate() == d && cDate.getMonth() == m && cDate.getFullYear() == y;
}
console.log(validateDate('22/05/2017')); // true
console.log(validateDate('22/05.2017')); // false
```

Comment: @Salman yeah, this works. Thanks for the info. Could you also please me understand why we have \2 instead of \1 for capturing group? I thought we would just write \1 to use the same capture group which we used earlier. And is that the reason numbers are available at 1st, 3rd and 4th position.

Comment: @whyAto8 there are 4 capturing groups in my regex, generated by `(` and `)`. It is the 2nd group that will contain `.` or `/`.

Comment: @Salman yeah, i realised that later. Have limited regex skill set. Anyway, thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't think of a way to tweak the regex. But here is an workaround with both separator specified.

```js
function validateDate(date) {
  var matches, d, m, y, cDate, format, dateFormatObj;
  dateFormatObj = {
    format1: /^(\d{2})[.](\d{2})[.](\d{4})$/,
    format2: /^(\d{2})[/](\d{2})[/](\d{4})$/,
    monthPos: 2,
    datePos: 1,
    yearPos: 3
  }
  format1 = dateFormatObj.format1;
  format2 = dateFormatObj.format2;
  matches = format1.exec(date) || format2.exec(date);

  if (matches == null)
    return false;

  d = matches[dateFormatObj.datePos];
  m = matches[dateFormatObj.monthPos] - 1;
  y = matches[dateFormatObj.yearPos];
  cDate = new Date(y, m, d);
  return cDate.getDate() == d && cDate.getMonth() == m && cDate.getFullYear() == y;
}

alert(validateDate('22/05.2017'))
```

Comment: @Puzagh yeah, this works as a workaround..but I would be more inclined to use a capture group, as i will keep on adding more separators.