# Regex how to match consistent signs?

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python regex to match dates in forms as: 1999-01-01 or 1999.1.1 or 1999-1-1. but not ones like 1999.1-1 or 1999-1.1.i.e. the signs between year month and day must be consistent. I use the following code to do it which is messy. is there a better way to do it?

```
import regex as re
re.fullmatch('(((((19|20)\d\d-(([1-9])|((0[1-9]|1[012])))-(?p)([1-9]|(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))(\.)?))))|' \
    '(((((19|20)\d\d\/(([1-9])|((0[1-9]|1[012])))/(?p)([1-9]|(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))(\.)?))))|'\
    '(((((19|20)\d\d\.(([1-9])|((0[1-9]|1[012])))\.(?p)([1-9]|(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))(\.)?))))','1999.1.1')
```

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43497231/date-format-regex-to-match-date-separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\b\d+(\W)\d+\1\d+\b
```

You can use something based on these lines.
See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nVCBSy/1/

Basically, you capture a group and later see if its there again.

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
\d{4}([-/.])\d{1,2}\1\d{1,2}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/0FVKOX/1/). The clue here is to use a backreference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
import re

s = '''1999-01-01 or 1999.1.1 or 1999-1-1
but not 1999.1-1 or 1999-1.1'''

matches = re.findall(r'(\d{4})([.-])(\d{1,2})\2(\d{1,2})', s)

dates = []
for match in matches:
    dates.append((match[0], match[2], match[3]))

print(dates)
```